# Where should I put the middleware if a sub router module used in Express.js

Tags: express, file-upload

All:

When I learn how to upload file with Express.js, there is a middleware called multer ( https://github.com/expressjs/multer ), and from its Usage example:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})

app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is array of `photos` files
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
})

var cpUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'gallery', maxCount: 8 }])
app.post('/cool-profile', cpUpload, function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is an object (String -> Array) where fieldname is the key, and the value is array of files
  //
  // e.g.
  //  req.files['avatar'][0] -> File
  //  req.files['gallery'] -> Array
  //
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
})
```

The middleware object directly used in app.js, I wonder if I use sub router like:

**app.js**

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use("/", routes);
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
    debugger;
  console.log(req.body.upld);
  console.log(req.file);
  res.send("");
});


module.exports = router;
```

I wonder where should I put that upload middleware? Should I put that var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }) in each file use it? If so, will this cause several uploads folders generated in different folders based on the router file located?

Thanks